# CallLog.Calls Query By Date

Tags: android

I am querying CallLog.Calls content provider for call details. Everything works fine except when I try to query by dates. That is, to get call details for a particular date or date range etc. I know the date are stored as long (millisecond format) so I tried to convert the date first and then query by it, but I must be doing something wrong here. Here's the query I am running, pls note that it works well when I remove the "WHERE DATE =" part or replace it by something like "WHERE TYPE=" etc. So, how do I run a query to get call details for a date or date range? Any help on this? Thanks.

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
               CallLog.Calls.DATE + "<=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(dateSTR)}, ORDER_BY);
        startManagingCursor(c);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how i do it:

```
Cursor c = contentResolver.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] { CallLog.Calls.DATE, CallLog.Calls.DURATION,
                        CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, CallLog.Calls._ID },
                CallLog.Calls.DATE + ">?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(resetDate.getTime())},
                CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + " asc");
```

resetDate is a Date variable, set to the beginning of the period i want to cover.

Comment: I tried this and it seems to be working. But I am having a weird prob though, if I try to filter by date like  CallLog.Calls.DATE + ">?, it seems to work but if I try it like  CallLog.Calls.DATE + "=?, it always returns no value and doesn't show any error either. What may be the prob, am I doing the query wrong way?

Comment: When you query for CallLog.Calls.DATE + "=?" you will almost always get an empty result set, since you check for a call made at exactly that millisecond. Try something like  CallLog.Calls.DATE + ">? and " +  CallLog.Calls.DATE + "<?" to check for a range

Comment: Oh. It all makes sense now. How did it never occurred to me? Thanks for the help.