# Querying CallLog.Calls by Current Date

Tags: android

I am querying the `CallLog.Calls` content provider for call details. I do something of this kind

```
Cursor managedCursor = cr.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, null);
```

By this way I get all the Call Logs. But now I want to query by the Current Date so that I get only the Current date calllogs. How should one approach this?

Comment: I believe this has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516423/calllog-calls-query-by-date)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
//With this method you will get the timestamp of today at midnight
public long getTodayTimestamp(){
    Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c1.setTime(new Date()); 

    Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c2.set(Calendar.YEAR, c1.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    c2.set(Calendar.MONTH, c1.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    c2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    c2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    c2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    c2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    return c2.getTimeInMillis();
}

String timestap = String.valueOf(getTodayTimestamp());

Cursor managedCursor = cr.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, CallLog.Calls.DATE + ">= ?", new String[]{timestamp}, null);
```

Comment: I tried this solution and it worked but the query should be        Cursor managedCursor = cr.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + ">= ?", new String[]{timestamp}, null);

Comment: Sorry, i wrote the code but i didn't tested it so there is a parameter more than the ones accepted :)

Comment: Also the Hour format should be of the  form c2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);  to support 24-hour format.

Comment: What about if i want to get all the call per current date?? Plzz any idea?